# Diff of command output between files in two directories with different names

Tags: bash, for-loop, command-line, diff

Hope this makes sense. I want to diff the output of a specific command between two files, with slightly different names. I just want a one to one comparison. My directory structure is like this:

```
directory1:         directory2:
file1_serv1         file1_serv2
file2_serv1         file2_serv2
```

What I have so far:

```
for i in directory1/*; do
  for j in directory2/*; do
    diff <(wgrib2 -var "$i") <(wgrib2 -var "$j")
  done
done
```

I really only want the results of the diff between `file1_serv1 file1_serv2` and `file2_serv1 file2_serv2` but it instead does this (which I understand the logic of, I just don't know how to get my intended result):

```
file1_serv1 file1_serv2  
file1_serv1 file2_serv2  
file2_serv1 file1_serv2
file2_serv1 file2_serv2
```

Comment: Nested loops make a cross product between the two lists, they don't loop in parallel.

Comment: How are the filenames in the two directories related, so you know which ones to diff with each other?

Comment: are you guaranteed to have the same number of files in both directories?

Comment: @markp-fuso yes guaranteed to have the same number in each directory

Comment: @Barmar the filenames are the same up to a certain number of characters, but even that varies for each file...basically they're from two different servers so the end of each file has something like "_server1" or "_server2".

Comment: So loop over the files in directory1. Replace the directory name with directory2, and replace `_server1` with `_server2`. Then compare those two files.

Comment: please update the sample filenames in the question to more accurately show what you're working with, and make sure to explicitly list which file pairs are to be diff'd; right now there's no way (for us) to know that `file1` and `file3` are to be diff'd other than the order in which the filenames appear when sorted

Comment: @markp-fuso updated, hope that better conveys what I mean...the filenames are the same before the underscore that specifies the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a single loop, not nested loops. Use substitution operators to transform the filename from one directory to the corresponding filename in the other directory.

```
for file1 in directory1/*
do
    file2=${file1/directory1/directory2}
    file2=${file2/_server1/_server2}
    diff <(wgrib2 -var "$file1") <(wgrib2 -var "$file2")
done
```

Answer (score 1):

This [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean code should do what I think you are trying to do with the code in the question:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

dir1_files=( directory1/* )
dir2_files=( directory2/* )

for i in "${!dir1_files[@]}"; do
    diff <(wgrib2 -var "${dir1_files[i]}") <(wgrib2 -var "${dir2_files[i]}")
done
```

It assumes that the files you want to process together are always at the same index of the sorted lists of directory entries.  That seems like a very big assumption.  The approach recommended by Barmar is probably a better option.